# Meaning of "in a stunned heap"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He lay in a stunned heap.

I can't decide this sentence structure.Does it mean
"Lay in a heap being stunned" or "lay stunned in a heap" ?

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/collapse-fall-in-a-heap

Comment: I would go with the second one. To me, there's no implication that he's "being stunned" still.

Answer (score 1):

It means that he was so stunned that his muscles lost their rigidity, and his body lost its poise.

It is similar to how something very upsetting or surprising can cause us to be open mouthed.

A good alternative to the phrase "stunned heap" would be "**slumped**".